# In TinyMCE the upload image name is different depending on whether you use drag-and-drop or file upload. Can we retain the original name?

Tags: tinymce

I implemented a backend to upload images and save them on a server with unique names that are based on the original name with an appended ms timestamp to keep them unique.

When I use the drag-and-drop interface it retains the original filename, like this:

```
hands-1614581114338.jpeg
```

But if I use the file upload dialog a "blob" based name, with its own unique timestamp name, is created instead, like this:

```
blobid1614589991819-1614590017686.jpg
```

Is there a way of having the file upload dialog work name files the same way as the drag-and-drop interface?

I tried

```
images_reuse_filename: true
```

but apparently that is for something else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Custom upload handler:

```
images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
    let xhr, formData;
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = false;
    xhr.open('POST', 'upladhandler.php');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        let json;

        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
            return;
        }

        json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
            failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
            return;
        }
        success(json.location);
    };
    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.blob().name);
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Server side:

```
$original_filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look. I'm not currently using upload_hander at all. I guess just the default stuff. On the server-side I'm not using PHP; I'm using a server-side Javascript. It looks easy enough to try though. I'll report back.